# Sonarqube with smalll medium large test org

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to apply sonarqube analysis to our system.  The system is roughly laid out in multiple modules.  We have some small and medium tests in each module - and hope to create large tests in the future.  We are trying to use "Google" test naming.

Sonarqube seems to refer to unit and integration (roughly equivalent to small and medium in our environment).  I'm wondering if anyone knows a simple way to modify the labeling to better match what we are trying to setup.

Comment: What do you mean by _small_, _medium_ and _large_ tests? This seems to be a very uncommon classification…

Comment: I hadn't heard of it until I came to silicone valley either.  I think it's based on work at Google here:  [link](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2010/12/test-sizes.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to change the labels in SonarQube. Unit and integration tests are two very common types of tests, IMO you should stick to this convention.

Just to share some information: at SonarSource, we have unit tests, medium tests and integration tests, and when we analyse our code on our internal SonarQube instance, the medium tests end up in the "unit test" category (they are executed at the same time BTW).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to switch the labels Unit -> Small and Integration -> Medium by creating a language pack plugin.  I started from the French language pack, and modified the existing core.properties file.  The solution gives me a "localized" version of site using our naming convention.