# Can I track more than two test categories on Sonarqube?

Tags: testing, sonarqube

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019653/sonarqube-with-smalll-medium-large-test-org) and got the impression that the only two categories of tests that can be used are *unit tests* and *integration tests*.

However, my project also has end-to-end (*e2e*) tests, that don't really fit into the integration test category (like Fabrice suggested in his answer to the aforementioned question). Thus, I would like to be able to track how many e2e-tests were run, how many were skipped, how many failed, and so on.
The e2e-tests output junit xml-files.

Is this possible to do with some existing plugin? I.e. to have three (or why not more) categories of tests: unit, integration and e2e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by forking [this repository](https://github.com/nvnoorloos/sonar-javascript-integrationtests) on Github and developing that plugin for my own needs. Thanks to nvnoorloos and other contributors!

In essence, I just had to define new metrics and update the widget code to display the correct metrics. The parser didn't require any changes just to get the numbers (test amount, successful, skipped, failed, errors and execution time).